# List ranges and the total count based on condition

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

**Table Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblMaster](
    [SID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    [VID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] default (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [CharToAdd] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Start] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [End] [int] NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblDetails](
    [DetailsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    [SID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Sno] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ConcatenatedText] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [isIssued] [bit] default (0) NOT NULL,
    [isUsed] [bit] default (0) NOT NULL
)
GO
```

**Sample Data:**

```
Insert into dbo.TblMaster Values (1,default, 'CA', 1, 5)
Insert into dbo.TblMaster Values (1,default, 'PA', 1, 5)
GO
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(1, 1, 'CA1', 0,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(1, 2, 'CA2', 0,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(1, 3, 'CA3', 0,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(1, 4, 'CA4', 1,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(1, 5, 'CA5', 0,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(2, 1, 'PA1', 0,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(2, 2, 'PA2', 0,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(2, 3, 'PA3', 1,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(2, 4, 'PA4', 0,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(2, 5, 'PA5', 0,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(3, 1, '1', 0,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(3, 2, '2', 1,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(3, 3, '3', 1,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(3, 4, '4', 0,0)
Insert into dbo.TblDetails values(3, 5, '5', 0,0)
    GO
```

**Expected Output:**

[image]

**Query I have built as of now:**

```
Declare @VID INT  = 1

    ;WITH Tmp as
    (
      SELECT 
            TM.CharToAdd as Prefix, 
            sno,
            sno - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sno) as grp
      FROM dbo.TblDetails TD
      LEFT JOIN dbo.TblMaster TM on TM.[SID] = TD.[SID]             
      WHERE isIssued = 0 and isUsed = 0 
            AND  TM.VID = @VID 
    )
    SELECT  Prefix,
            MIN(sno) as RangeStart,
            MAX(sno) as RangeEnd,
            COUNT(*) as [Count]
    FROM Tmp
    GROUP BY grp, Prefix
```

In the TblDetails table want to find the range of available values and its total counts from all records whose bit columns are 0. If bit column is 1 then it means it is already used so I am trying to skip it and list rest as available records. Doubtful whether am I explaining the problem statement well so have provided the sample data and expected output for better understanding.  I did try doing some recursive function but the result isn't matching the expected output. So looking for help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close...

**CODE**

```
Declare @VID INT  = 1

;with cte as(
    select
        m.CHarToAdd,
        d.sno,
        d.sno - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by m.CharToAdd ORDER BY sno) as grp
    from 
        TblMaster m
        inner join
            TblDetails d on
            d.sid = m.sid
    where
        d.isIssued = 0 and d.isUsed = 0 and m.vid = @VID)

select
    CharToAdd,
    min(sno) as Start,
    max(sno) as [End],
    (max(sno) - min(sno) + 1) as [Count]
from cte
group by
    CHarToAdd, grp
order by
    CHarToAdd
```

**RESULTS**

```
CharToAdd   Start   End Count
CA             1    3   3
CA             5    5   1
PA             1    2   2
PA             4    5   2
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Comment: @prasanth  no problem